# what does mean "scheme and: bad syntax in: and"

Tags: scheme, racket

I am getting the following error "and: bad syntax in: and

```
#lang racket

(define fold 
    (lambda (fn lst)
        (if (null? (cdr lst))
            (car lst)  
            (fn (car lst) (fold fn (cdr lst)))
        )
    )
)

(define none-diff?
    (lambda (lst num) 
        (if (even? num) 
            (fold and (map even? lst))
            (fold and (map odd?  lst))
        )
    )
)
```

I try foldr in szScheme , the same error , I do not know why ?

1. (fold + (list 1 2 3)) : ok
2. (fold and (map (even? (list 1 2 3)))) : error

"and" and "+" are  function , but ?

Answer (score 4):

[`And`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._and%29%29) isn't function, but [macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html). And macros can't be used as argument for higher-order functions (for example `map`, `apply` or `foldl` variants).

In this case, you can use [`andmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29):

```
> (andmap even? (list 2 4 6))
#t
> (andmap even? (list 1 2 3))
#f
```

Comment: `and` is not a macro.

Answer (score 1):

```
(fold and
      (map (even? (list 1 2 3))))
```

- `fold` almost sure requires 3 arguments
- `and` is not a function, but a special form
- you pass `map` a single argument
- a list cannot be even.

Comment: `and` is not a special operator.  Scheme doesn't really distinguish between macros and special operators the way CL does (`and` is not a special operator in CL though), but [R7RS](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) defines expressions with `and` as 'derived expressiona' (see p63) which clearly means it is defined in terms of more primitive syntax (specifically `if`): so it's not a primitive construct which is what 'special form' means in CL.  In Racket you can easily find the macro definition of `and`.

Comment: @ignisvolens I looked in the code of mit/scheme, where it has dedicated scode, so  it is special form.  But yes, you can define it as derived as well.